# Deleting a file from storage does not delete an image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-storage

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to delete an image from storage directory.

Basically the images is placed at this dir:

```
/storage/app/public/laboratories/labs/21/pics
```

And I tried running this method:

```
public function removeAzPic($lab,$azpic)
    {
        $destinationPath = storage_path("laboratories/labs/$lab/pics/$azpic");
        
        Storage::delete($destinationPath);

        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

But the problem is it does not delete the file from storage!

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: provide full path. for example: `unlink(storage_path('app/image/20201225130625.png'));`

Comment: Does the containing folder and file have the correct permissions?

Comment: Have you tried deleting a file using the [`Storage`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#deleting-files) facade?

Comment: @Peppermintology I just updated the question using this Facade, would u mind plz check it out...

Comment: You don't need to specify `storage_path`. The `Storage` facade will automatically use the default storage location. If you have multiple storage locations you can specify which storage location to use (e.g. `->disk('s3');`) but in your case, I don't think you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this function to the helper.php for to delete files/directories recursively:

Function will help you to delete files at the moment. If you want to delete directories change   **if ( is_dir($full) ) {** to   **if ( is_file($full) ) {**

```php
public static function rrmdir($src = null) {

        if(!is_dir($src)) return false;

        $dir = opendir($src);
        while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) {
            if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
                $full = $src . '/' . $file;
                if ( is_dir($full) ) {
                    self::rrmdir($full);
                }  else {
                    @unlink($full);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
        rmdir($src);

        return true;
    }
```